# How to serialize first photo in album? Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to serialize first photo in album if photo connected by using FK with model Gallery. I need first photo for gallery cover in galley list.
My models:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

class GalleryImage(models.Model):
    gallery_id = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, related_name='photos')
    photo = models.ImageField()
```

**Anyone have any ideas?** May be I need suchlike request Gallery.objects.get(id=id).photos.first() but  i not sure is it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get` returns only one object. `filter` returns multiple objects. You can access the `ForeignKey` fields with `__`.

```
Gallery.objects.get(photos__id=id)
```

Comment: Where can I make this request? Views or serilizers?

Comment: In views you have to add.

Comment: Thanks for answer